# Yahoo Pipes and Website Name

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo-pipes

How do I fetch Page Name with Yahoo Pipes?

I'm making a news / blog aggregator, and need to know the name of the site where the info is coming from (bbc, cnn, fox, etc).

Do I need to do this with REGEX?

Anyone that can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the page using the **XPath Fetch Page** or **Fetch Feed** modules in the **Sources** menu. Maybe with others too.

After that you can extract the page name itself using the various operators, possibly **Regex**, or others, depending on the source page you are using and the output you want to get.

In general your question is too broad and difficult to answer. To get you started, I created an example pipe that extracts the title of your question from this post, which is basically the "page name" of the current page.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=668acf3f807c30d7b75f12459edd3252

I used the **XPath Fetch Page** with parameters:

- URL = this page
- Extract using XPath = `//div[@id="question-header"]`

I got that `div` path by inspecting the source code of this page, where I saw that `div#question-header` is the container of a question. I could have selected a deeper inner container or a higher level container. It all depends on the amount of other information you need. The more information you want to you from the page, the higher level container you select.

Next, I used the **Create RSS** operator to create a proper RSS feed, with parameters:

- Title = `h1.a`
- Link = `h1.a.href`

I chose these elements because in the container I extracted with xpath, the page name is inside `h1 a`. In Yahoo Pipes you use a dot as the path separator.

Answer (score 0):

I found this sample pipe http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=69b5dce1c59501a0c64a660c1cfdb856. The page title included the name of the site too. I am not sure if this what you are looking for.